# In javascript when creating a new object, the array property in it does not initializes as a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am creating 5 new objects of type "RoundDiv" using for loop, it has a property "weirdArray", which is an empty array. Upon calling "init()" method. "someValue" is pushed into the "weirdArray".

The problem is "someValue" is pushed only once each time a new object of type "RounDiv" is created but on clicking any "roundDiv" the console log shows 5 elements in the array, whereas there should be only one.

```js
    "use strict";

    var roundDivPrototype = {
      weirdArray: new Array(),
      init: function(label) {
        this.weirdArray.push("someValue");
        var me = this;
        var body = document.body;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "roundDiv";
        div.innerText = label;
        div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          alert("Length of array: " + me.weirdArray.length);
          console.log(me.weirdArray); //me=this
        });

        body.appendChild(div);
      }
    };
    var RoundDiv = function(label) {
      this.init(label);
    };
    RoundDiv.prototype = roundDivPrototype;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      new RoundDiv(i);
    }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.roundDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**I figured out a possible solution to the problem:**

```js
"use strict";

var roundDivPrototype = {
  weirdArray: undefined,
  init: function(label) {
    this.weirdArray = new Array();  //Change in code above
    this.weirdArray.push("someValue");  //Change in code above

    var me = this;
    var body = document.body;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "roundDiv";
    div.innerText = label;
    div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      alert("Length of array: " + me.weirdArray.length); //me=this
      console.log(me.weirdArray); //me=this
    });

    body.appendChild(div);
  }
};
var RoundDiv = function(label) {
  this.init(label);
};
RoundDiv.prototype = roundDivPrototype;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new RoundDiv(i);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.roundDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Although I figured out a possible solution to the problem but still want to know why previous values in "weirdArray" are present when I'm creating a new object of type "RoundDiv"...

Your contribution is deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you instantiate `weirdArray` in the object prototype, making this array property static. Therefore, each of your `RoundDiv` objects will share the same array to store your data.

Instantiating it in the `init` function as you do in your second example solves the problem. A new instance of `weirdArray` will be created each time you create a new `RoundDiv`.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu6k3w2e/6/) that shows for each example how many times a new array is created, when, and the array size after each `push`.

Comment: Yes, and also, you don't need to set it to undefined in the prototype; just defining in the init() function is sufficient. For this reaaon, personally I usually only declare methods, not data properties, in the prototype...although of course it would still be fine to declare primitive defaults (e.g. numbers of strings rather than objects or arrays) in the prototype if you prefer.

Comment: @PratikKedia See also: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1566-using-super-constructors-is-critical-in-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript.htm